# How to generate unique IDs en masse based on JSON data?

Tags: javascript

I have data as such:

```json
const data = [
    {
        "category": "food",
        "brand": "McDonalds",
         "name": "McSpicy",
    },
    {
        "category": "food",
        "brand": "McDonalds",
         "name": "Double Cheese",
    },
    {
        "category": "drink",
        "brand": "Coca-cola",
         "name": "Coke",
    },
    {
        "category": "drink",
        "brand": "Sprite",
         "name": "Sprite",
    },
    {
        "category": "drink",
        "brand": "Coca-cola",
         "name": "Pepsi",
    },
    {
        "category": "food",
        "brand": "KFC",
         "name": "Fried Chicken",
    },
]
```

So I want to generate IDs for each of them in the format of `${categoryId} + ${brand} + ${index}` so it would the data above would have IDs as such:

```
0001MCDO0001,
0001MCDO0002,
0002COCA0001,
0002SPRI0001,
0002COCA0002,
0001XKFC0001,
```

The first 4 digits are the category ID, in this example `food` has the id of `1` and `drink` has the id of `2`. Second 4-digits are the first 4 letters of the brand uppercased and last 4 digits are just increment.

So far I am able to get the first 8 digits, but I'm a little confused on how I can generate the last 4 digits (increment). What I have:

```js
const formatId = (newProduct) => {
    let formatted = undefined;
    const category = categoryProduct.find(
      (category) =>
        category.name.replaceAll(" ", "").toLowerCase() ===
        newProduct.category.replaceAll(" ", "").toLowerCase()
    );

    const brandId = (
      "XXX" + newProduct.brand.replaceAll(" ", "").slice(0, 4).toUpperCase()
    ).slice(-4);

    const categoryId = ("000" + category.id).slice(-4);

    const duplicateLen = products.filter(
      (obj) => obj.category === newProduct.category && obj.brand === newProduct.brand
    ).length;

    if (duplicateLen === 0) {
      formatted = categoryId + brandId + "0001";
    } else {
      formatted =
        categoryId +
        brandId +
        ("000" + (duplicateLen + 1)).slice(-4);
    }

    return formatted;
  };
```

The code above is usable when I'm trying to add 1 product at a time. I am a little stuck on how I can implement this when I'm trying to add multiple products at once (bulk update).

## Additional Info

`categoryProduct` is basically an array of objects as such:

```js
const categoryProducts = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "food",
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "drink",
    },
]
```

and `products` are basically `data` which I have stated above.

So basically the idea is to check first in `products` / `data` if there are items with similar category and brand. Then we want to check in the new bulk data, if there are duplicates as well (part where I'm confused). Then do increment accordingly.

How I'm applying the function is as such:

```js
data.forEach((obj) => {
   obj.id = formatId(obj);

   for (var i in obj) {
       if (obj[i] === undefined) {
           obj[i] = "";
   }
}
});
```

Comment: What `jenisId` is? Please create a complete snippet with all code.

Comment: _"last 4 digits are just increment"_... from what base? They seem to reset for each category as it's encountered.

Comment: "*I am a little stuck on how I can implement this when I'm trying to add multiple products at once*" And the reason you can't just use `for` or `foreach` to loop through is...? What is the problem you are actually encountering when you are coding this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of use `products` for duplicate value, i used final array with `filter` like:

```js
const products = [{
    "category": "food",
    "brand": "McDonalds",
    "name": "McSpicy",
  },
  {
    "category": "food",
    "brand": "McDonalds",
    "name": "Double Cheese",
  },
  {
    "category": "drink",
    "brand": "Coca-cola",
    "name": "Coke",
  },
  {
    "category": "drink",
    "brand": "Sprite",
    "name": "Sprite",
  },
  {
    "category": "drink",
    "brand": "Coca-cola",
    "name": "Pepsi",
  },
  {
    "category": "food",
    "brand": "KFC",
    "name": "Fried Chicken",
  },
];
const categoryProduct = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "food",
    counter: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "drink",
    counter: 1,
  },
];
const formatId = (newProduct) => {
  let formatted = undefined;
  const category = categoryProduct.find(
    (category) =>
    category.name.replaceAll(" ", "").toLowerCase() ===
    newProduct.category.replaceAll(" ", "").toLowerCase()
  );

  const brandId = (
    "XXX" + newProduct.brand.replaceAll(" ", "").slice(0, 4).toUpperCase()
  ).slice(-4);

  const categoryId = ("000" + category.id).slice(-4);

  const duplicateLen = final.filter(el =>  el.substring(0,8) === categoryId + brandId).length;
  
  if (duplicateLen === 0) {
    formatted = categoryId + brandId + "0001";
  } else {
    formatted =
      categoryId +
      brandId +
      ("000" + (duplicateLen + 1)).slice(-4);
  }

  return formatted;
};
const final = [];
products.forEach(el => {
  final.push(formatId(el));
});
console.log(final);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create indexed data structures for faster lookups of things like category ID
2. Create helper functions for each ID section
3. Map over the initial array to create a new one with IDs added
4. Keep track of the category and brand combination in another data structure so you know when to increment the *index*

```js
const data = [{"category":"food","brand":"McDonalds","name":"McSpicy"},{"category":"food","brand":"McDonalds","name":"Double Cheese"},{"category":"drink","brand":"Coca-cola","name":"Coke"},{"category":"drink","brand":"Sprite","name":"Sprite"},{"category":"drink","brand":"Coca-cola","name":"Pepsi"},{"category":"food","brand":"KFC","name":"Fried Chicken"}];
const categoryProducts = [{"id":1,"name":"food"},{"id":2,"name":"drink"}];

// Index categories
const categoryMap = Object.fromEntries(
  categoryProducts.map(({ id, name }) => [name, id.toString()])
);

// Helpers
const hashCategory = ({ category }) => categoryMap[category].padStart(4, "0");
const hashBrand = ({ brand }) =>
  brand.replace(/\W/g, "").slice(0, 4).toUpperCase().padStart(4, "X");

// Brand / category indexes
const categoryIndex = {};

const newData = data.map((obj) => {
  const key = hashCategory(obj) + hashBrand(obj);
  categoryIndex[key] = (categoryIndex[key] ?? 0) + 1;
  return {
    id: key + categoryIndex[key].toString().padStart(4, "0"),
    ...obj,
  };
});

console.log(newData);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be cleaner to use a factory pattern.

```
const data = [
  {
      "category": "food",
      "brand": "McDonalds",
       "name": "McSpicy",
  },
  {
      "category": "food",
      "brand": "McDonalds",
       "name": "Double Cheese",
  },
  {
      "category": "drink",
      "brand": "Coca-cola",
       "name": "Coke",
  },
  {
      "category": "drink",
      "brand": "Sprite",
       "name": "Sprite",
  },
  {
      "category": "drink",
      "brand": "Coca-cola",
       "name": "Pepsi",
  },
  {
      "category": "food",
      "brand": "KFC",
       "name": "Fried Chicken",
  },
]

class IdFactory {
  _catIdMap = new Map();
  _catId = 0;
  _idxMap = new Map();

  getId(data) {
    const {category, brand, name} = data;
    let catId = this._catIdMap.get(category);

    if (!catId) {
      catId = ++this._catId;
      this._catIdMap.set(category, catId);
    }

    const lpad = (i) => ("0000" + i).slice(-4);

    const brandId = ("XXX" + brand.replaceAll(" ", "").slice(0, 4).toUpperCase()).slice(-4);

    const pfx =  `${lpad(catId)}${brandId}`
    let idx = this._idxMap.get(pfx);
    if (idx) {
      this._idxMap.set(pfx, ++idx);
    } else {
      idx = 1;
      this._idxMap.set(pfx, 1);
    }
    return `${pfx}${lpad(idx)}`;    
  }
}

const f = new IdFactory()
console.log(data.map(d => f.getId(d)));
```